# PAW server configuration : Use internal HTML folder instead of sd card

Tags: android, embedded

I have used PAW server 
I have stored my website in internal html folder instead of SD card.
I want to change configuration of PAW server in such a way that Paw server will use my internal html folder for run web instead of sd card html folder.

I have used android 4.4 on my embedded board

Answer (score 2):

The handler configuration is (normally) located inside the /sdcard/paw/conf/handler.xml file.
You could edit the existing configuration by changing the paths specified inside the File Handler section, or you could insert a new File Handler definition.
If you use a new definition, make sure that the ID is different from the existing one.
An new File Handler definition could look like this:

```
<handler status="active">
<name>File Handler 2</name>
<description></description>
<removable>true</removable>
<id>filehandler2</id>
<files />
<params>
<param name="filehandler2.class" value="sunlabs.brazil.server.FileHandler" />
    <param name="filehandler2.root" value="/wherever/html" />
    <param name="filehandler2.defaults" value="index.html" />
</params>
</handler>
```

Comment: my resources are not loading in paw server(giving 404 response). Where should i place them?